# How to integrate CAPTCHA in a search form with Views

Tags: 7, views, captcha

I have created a search page with the Views module, which includes a few exposed filter criteria. The form will be available to guest users, so I would like to include a CAPTCHA in the form.

The CAPTCHA module has been installed and works just fine in the user registration, but I cannot figure out how to integrate it inside the search page.

PS: I am using Drupal 7.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the CAPTCHA configuration page, there should be an option to "Add CAPTCHA administration links to forms". If you enable this then visit your views page, an option should appear to add a CAPTCHA next to the exposed filter (the option may be a little mangled depending on your layout, it expands out fine when you click it).

A heads up that this can sometimes generate [some extra warnings](http://drupal.org/node/1064158), see how you go.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Unfortunately, I do get the warnings and the issue at the link you provided is still not resolved. No luck with the reCAPTCHA, but it does work with the Math question. Yay! :-)